# Laravel 5.7 - Custom Validation Message parsley

Tags: jquery, parsley.js, parsley

I am developing a system and in my system I implemented the parsley. I want to change the validation message when the certain field didn't meet the requirement.

```
For example

Name Input
Description Input
Rate Input
```

My parsley validation is working when all fields are missing. In my rate input field I want to change the validation to "Decimal Only" after submitting the form.

What I have right now is, when I clicked the view button modal will show. All the information will be listed inside of the modal, in the bottom part i have edit button.

When I clicked the edit button all the label / p will be change into input field(I used jquery here).

**Modal**

```
<form id=".." data-parsley-validate novalidate>

</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
Appending
$('#wht_rate_view').append('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="wht_rate" id="wht_rate" value="'+wht_rate_view+'" data-parsley-error-message="sss" required/>');
 $('div').on('submit','form#update-wht-form',function(e){
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "Once saved, you will not be able to change your key information!",
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: true,
                dangerMode: true,
              })
              .then((willSave) => {
                if (willSave) {
                  $.ajaxSetup({
                     headers: {
                         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                     }
                  })
                   $.ajax({
                     url: '/configurations/taxes/updateWHT',
                     type: "POST",
                     data: formData,
                     beforeSend: function() {
                        $('.update-wht').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                     },
                     success: function(response) {
                         if (response != '') {
                            $('#get-wht-table').DataTable().destroy();
                            getWHTTable();
                            $('#update-wht-form').trigger("reset");
                            swal("Withholding Tax has been updated!", {
                              icon: "success",
                            });
                            $('#view-wht-details').modal('hide');
                         }
                     },
                     complete: function() {
                        $('.update-wht').removeAttr('disabled');
                     }
                  });
                } else {
                  swal("Save Aborted");
                }
              });

          e.preventDefault();
          return false;


    });
```

NOTE: I used sweetalert for the message

Question: How can I change the validation message?

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-parsley-<constraint>-message="my message"` attribute, where `<constraint>` should be the name of your constraint (e.g `required`).